# javascript and php - login script

Tags: php, javascript, login-script

I am begginer in programming, I commented the rows, where I dont understand the code.
And the connection to database is ok, so I do not understand why it is not working.

HERE IS LOGIN.PHP

```
<?php

include("connectiondbs.php");
include("javascript.js");
session_start();
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
{
$u=$_POST['username'];
$p=$_POST['password'];

$sql="SELECT userID FROM users WHERE login='$u' and password='$p'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
$row=mysql_fetch_array($result);

$active=$row['active'];            //I AM NOT SURE ABOUT THIS ONE

$count=mysql_num_rows($result);

if($count==1)
{
session_register("username");
session_register("password");     //HAS TO BE THE PASSWORD IN REGISTER?
$_SESSION['login_user']=$u;

header("location:succesfulllogin.php");  // HAS TO BE THIS FILE? OR I CAN GO TO THE MENU.HTML RIGHT NOW

}
else {
echo "Wrong Username or Password";
}}
?>

<form action="" method="post">
<label>Login :</label>
<input type="text" name="username"/><br />
<label>Password :</label>
<input type="password" name="password"/><br/>
<input type="submit" value=" Submit "/><br />
</form>
```

JAVASCRIPT.JS

```
<script Language="JavaScript">
    <!-- 
        function check_empty_field()
        {
        if (form.username.value == "" || form.password.value == "")
        {
           alert("Please fill in the password or login field.");
           return (false);
        }
        return (true);
        }
        -->
</script>
```

succesfulllogin.php

```
<?php
session_start();
if(!session_is_registered(username)){
header("location:login.php");
}
else{
header ("location:menu.html");
}
?>
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate your problem and explain what exactly "is not working"? What happens and what do you expect to happen? Do you get any errors, if yes, which ones? You just posted a bunch of code and expect us to find the problem whereas we don't even know where to look.

Comment: It returns me 
Wrong Username or Password
but I opened my database and I wrote the same login and password.
I expect the checking login, compare with database,
if login and password doesnt fit, It returns me to the login.php, else menu.html

Comment: And it is not checking empty field in my javascript code. It is doing nothing with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start, your javascript isn't being run. You're creating the function, but not calling it, and it doesn't interact with the PHP in any way. You can do that by changing your form tag to this:

```
<form action="login.php" method="post" onsubmit="return check_empty_field()">
```

Now the function check_empty_field runs whenever you submit the form. If it returns true, the form gets submitted and the PHP runs. Otherwise, it doesn't. For the function, change it to this (I put in some jQuery because it makes it 10x easier, if you're new to programming you should definitely look into it):

```
<script Language="JavaScript">
  <!--
    function check_empty_field()         // This is called when the submit
    {                                    // button is pressed
      if (form.username.value == "" || form.password.value == "")
      {
        alert("Please fill in the password or login field.");
        return false;                    // This doesn't submit the form
      }
      else
      {
        return true;                     // This submits the form
      }
    }
  -->
</script>
```

The jQuery makes a lot of this much easier, which is why I added it in. You can find more about it [here](http://api.jquery.com/). Of course, you'd have to put this at the top of your page, to make the jQuery work:

```
<script language="javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-2.0.1.min.js"></script>
```

This gets the jQuery definitions from the Microsoft CDN. It's rather reliable. It would be better to just put jQuery on your site, though, and then put in the path to the file.

Next, the PHP has some issues. Some have been covered by others, and pay attention to the previous answer, but to point out a few issues, `session_register` is not used anymore. Now you set session variables with `$_SESSION['variablename'] = 'value'`. You also have other issues to worry about, like validation and such. You should Google that.

If you want to know more about any of this, feel free to comment. I also can provide you with sources so you can learn more about the different parts of the code I used.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to go to `successfullogin.php`......as long as you put this at the top of your menu.html file.....which means you would rename it to `menu.php` file.  This will just deter people from going straight to menu.php....without being logged in.

```
<?php
session_start();
if(!session_is_registered(username)){
header("location:login.php");};?>
```

And...no you dont have to store the password in session, unless its being read somewhere else later down the line in your site. Check to make sure, but I doubt it is.  You probably don't need to store it.  So you can probably remove this line....

```
    session_register("password");     //HAS TO BE THE PASSWORD IN REGISTER?
```

You are also correct in being skeptical about this line......doesnt seem to be doing anything....you can probably remove it as well...

```
   $active=$row['active'];            //I AM NOT SURE ABOUT THIS ONE
```

Comment: Thank you.
And I would like to ask you ... There is problem with checking empty field in my javascript code, It is doing nothing with that. Maybe it is about method POST, because I found javascript code similar mine to checking that and there was method GET. Or there could be include .js in php?

Comment: Yeah well, that javascript isn't even being run by the looks of it......tell me...are you using Jquery at all?  Cuz I can just write you a quick function in Jquery.....and post

Comment: unfortunately I am not using Jquery. I have to say that I hear about that the first time(I am trying programming just few days), but I would like to learn something new

Comment: I made intex.html where was just labels, textboxes and this javascript code. But method were GET and it worked.